# does an update function in the API not raise exceptions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Before updating, I am running a query to get the town i want to update using an id. Now my assumptions are if the id does not exist I am supposed to have an error, but I am getting none.

```
def update_town(session, town_dict):
    try:
        town = session.query(Town).where(Town.id == town_dict["id"] )
        print(town)
        #setting new values
        town.update(town_dict)     
        session.commit() 
    except NoResultFound:
        return "not results found", 404
    return "ok"
```

Comment: what do you see printed by `print(town)`?  I think your query returns a result set, probably an empty set instead of an error?  It looks like to get a `NoResultFound` error you have to append `.one()` to your query https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html?highlight=noresultfound#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.one

Answer (score 0):

to check if this id exists, you could use .first()

```
town = session.query(Town).where(Town.id == town_dict["id"] ).first()
```

from the docs:

*Return the first result of this Query or None if the result doesn’t contain any row.*

you can then do a check, and only update town if this id exists:

```
if town:
    town.update()
    session.commit()
    return "ok"
else:
    return "not results found", 404
```

.first() is only one of many approaches for this, but it's pretty simple in practice. I wouldnt use a try-except block unless that's for some reason your preferred way